# Why is total = total + i so much faster than total += i?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

Why is total = total + i so much faster than total += i? Here is the code I ran multiple times:

```
var iterations = 1000000;
console.time('Operation total += i');
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    total += i;
};
console.timeEnd('Operation total += i');

console.time('Operation total = total + i');
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    total = total + i;
};
console.timeEnd('Operation total = total + i');
```

Here are some sample outputs:

- Operation total += i: 11.196ms
- Operation total = total + i: 9.561ms
- Operation total += i: 15.135ms
- Operation total = total + i: 8.936ms

Comment: "So much faster"... the difference of 6ms over one million loops isn't "so much faster". Also, when I execute this code I get different results every time. Sometimes the first is faster, sometimes the second.

Comment: This is a micro-optimization which can vary between engines.

Comment: If you reverse the order, running `total = total + i` before `total += i`, I get opposite results as well.

Comment: @Patrick2607 That's a 66% difference after averaging the times if OP is doing some computationally expensive work in-browser, it's pretty significant. That being said, I think OP did something based on my tests.

Comment: A random task running on the test system can easily swing the results by that much or more one way or the other.

Comment: I was just wondering if the compiler compiled those two operations the same or differently and I ran that same code maybe 8 times and each time the second += was slower.

Answer (score 11):

I ran the code 10 times, with the same iterations and with more iterations.

## 1 Millon iterations

### 1º time

I got this result:

> Operation total += i: 23.000ms
>   Operation total = total + i: 19.000ms

In this case, total+i is faster than total+=i

### 2º time

I got this result:

> Operation total += i: 25.000ms
>   Operation total = total + i: 31.000ms

In this case, total+i is slower than total+=i

I run the code 10 times more, similar results:

```
total+=i | total+i | diff  
71             76    -5  
23             19     4  
28             19     9  
23             18     5  
72             76    -4  
29             60    -31  
35             23     12  
72             74    -2  
23             19     4  
78             76     2
```

[image]

## 1 Billion iterations

### 1º time

> Operation total += i: 17324.000ms
>   Operation total = total + i: 15669.000ms

### 3º time

> Operation total += i: 15306.000ms
>   Operation total = total + i: 15401.000ms

I also executed that code 10 times. I got the same results, sometimes the first is faster, sometimes the second is.

**So in my opinion there is no evidence about that total+i is faster than total+=i.**

Comment: no evidence with a sample of 2 data points? (not even a third data point as a tie-breaker?)

Comment: It's not an opinion if you can prove it.

Comment: @ochi I run the code 10 times, and I increased iterations a lot, I run the code 10 times and I got the same results.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @ochi You need lots of consistent results to prove a point. You only need one counter-example to disprove it.

Comment: @Barmar generally speaking, maybe.  I'd argue that it depends - If, statistically speaking, you _can_ say that if 99% of the times A is faster than B then 1% of it being slower will not prevent you from saying that A is faster than B - the more data points, the more confident/accurate the statement is - what was not obvious to me in the first version of the answer was that he had ran his test millions of times (as opposed to two times only)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I ran a benchmark on Node.js with the Benchmark.js library using the following benchmarking code:

```
var iterations = 1000000;
suite.add('+= i', function() {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
            total += i;
    };
})
.add('= total +i', function() {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
            total = total + i;
    };
})
```

I didn't get any performance difference at all. Since Node.js and Google Chrome both use the V8 JS engine, there's probably something else going on. Perhaps there's it's specific to a certain version of V8? Or something went wrong with either either one of our benchmarks?

```
C:\test>node bench.js
+= i x 253 ops/sec ±1.37% (68 runs sampled)
= total +i x 254 ops/sec ±1.33% (70 runs sampled)
Fastest is = total +i,+= i

C:\test>node bench.js
+= i x 241 ops/sec ±3.03% (63 runs sampled)
= total +i x 246 ops/sec ±1.52% (67 runs sampled)
Fastest is = total +i,+= i

C:\test>node bench.js
+= i x 249 ops/sec ±2.04% (67 runs sampled)
= total +i x 249 ops/sec ±1.45% (68 runs sampled)
Fastest is = total +i,+= i
```

That being said, based on my multiple results, I would say that there is no difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer